# Woocommerce show/hide add_to_cart button for different variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My client has variable products where only some of the variations are purchasable.

Simple example:

Red tshirt:

- small (purchasable)
- medium (not purchasable)
- large (not purchasable)

The catch is we can't use the stock level or price to control whether it's purchasable or not.

I've created a custom checkbox `purchasable_variation` which is attached to each variation.

I'm stuck at how to use this field to show/hide the add to cart button.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. You can then use JS to listen for a variation change, and then test for the custom checkbox value.

```
$( '.single_variation_wrap' ).on( 'show_variation', function ( event, variation ) {
    if ( variation['purchasable_variation'] === 'yes' ) {
        $('.add_to_cart_button').show();
    } else {
        $('.add_to_cart_button').hide();
    }
});
```